# git flow: fatal: Index contains uncommited changes. Aborting

Tags: git, git-flow

I want to finish a feature using git flow but I get a fatal error: `fatal: Index contains uncommited changes. Aborting.`

```
>git --version
git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0

>git flow feature list
* google-oauth

>git branch
  develop
* feature/google-oauth
  master

>git flow feature finish google-oauth
fatal: Index contains uncommited changes. Aborting.

>git status
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in package.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
# On branch feature/google-oauth
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   app.js
```

Comment: so commit or discard those changes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you need to commit your changes (if you want to keep them)... `git flow feature finish` does not do this for you.

A simple: `git commit -m "my commit message"` should do the trick.

If you don't want to keep the changes.  You'll need to follow the instructions in the `git status` message and

> use "`git reset HEAD <file>...`" to unstage

Answer (score 3):

`git flow` message is self explanatory. It says

> Fatal: Index contains uncommitted changes. Aborting.

It simply says you need to commit your changes before you finish the flow. So if you want to have those changes, just do

```
git add app.js
git commit -m "Finished app.js code for google-oauth feature" //Or some other apt message
```

Just in case you do not want to have those changes (Discard), you can use `git stash`.

```
git stash
```

To get back your changes from stash, use

```
git stash apply
```